# How to use lists and loops to count the occurrences of dinucleotide pairs?

Tags: python, dna-sequence

I have a DNA text file and I need to specifically use lists and loops to count the occurrences of dinucleotide pairs (ex: AA, AC, AT, AG, CA, CC... etc) then use lists and loops again to print the counts to a new text file as a table with two columns separated by a tab: the dinucleotide sequence and the count. I know how to do this the long way (store each pair in variables then count occurrences using count, then open text file and print each individual counts to text file) but I am just now starting to learn about lists and loops and confused on how I would do it that way.

ex: this is how I do it:

dna1.txt is my (random) example of a dna sequence text file on my computer:

random sequence (i.e. dna1.txt):

agggaatcgctggtgaagaggttgtgacctcttataaccccattgttaatgaggtccacg
ctaagtaatgagtggctggtataggtgacgtctagaagtcatttctgtacagttactgcc
gtggatatatccattaggacgacactggggtgctcccacgcaccacgtgtacaggacgac
tgcgatgatatagaaggtgagcttaaaacgttctacaaccccaatgaatcatagccgggt
agattgccaggcgtgtggtaacgggtacgtggcggatctcgtccagtatgccgcagtcac
acccgaatctttcgtcgactacggagcgactcgtatcgagacgggcttgaattgactcct
catggattaggctgaggtcaaccttcgcatggagcctgggcatttaaaggtcgactgtcg

```
dna_txt = open("dna1.txt")
dna_txtcontents = dna_txt.read()
aa_count = dna_txtcontents.count("aa")
print str(aa_count)
```

then continue for each pair  then store each individual count in a new text file but how do I make it easier for myself by using lists and loops to both count occurrences of each pair then store counts in a new text file? Oh and also making sure that the program would work whether the sequence is uppercase or lowercase?

Thank you!!

Comment: `aa_count = dna_txtcontents("AA")` would throw an error. Are you claiming this code works, or are you saying this is how you would do it with lists?

Comment: sorry, I meant to add .count at the end there but yes this works but this is the long version. Confused on how I would do the same exact thing but lists and loops instead?

Comment: I'm not a biologist, are all possible pairs of `ACTG` possible? Or can only `A` and `T` pair, and `G` and `C`?

Comment: a dna text file includes a dna sequence                                                                                    ex: >random sequence
ctacgataaccatccatgacatcgaaggctgcagcctatgaagcattgggcgtttactgg
acatggggtgaaagtgggtgcagttcaaagagttgttttttgctgtccgaccgactggag
agtgatccgatacgccaagggcttcattacgggtaagaacatttggtatattaatgtaat
aagccgttcggtgggtgtca
                                                                                                                                                 by nucleotide pairs, i mean how many aa's, ac's, ca's etc... are in a sequence such as this one?

Comment: To make sure that the program would work for lower and upper case you can write `dna_txtcontents = dna_txt.read().upper()` that way all letters become uppercase.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) to create all dinucleotide pairs. To make it case-insensitive, convert everything to lowercase (or uppercase).

```
import itertools

with open("dna1.txt") as dna_txt:
    dna_txtcontents = dna_txt.read().upper()

nt_pair_counts = {}
for nt_pair in itertools.product('ACTG', repeat=2):
    nt_pair = "".join(nt_pair)
    nt_pair_counts[nt_pair] = dna_txtcontents.count(nt_pair)

with open("out.txt", "wt", encoding="utf-8") as fd:
    for nt, count in nt_pair_counts.items():
        print(nt, count, sep="\t", file=fd)
```

Comment: This is what I was getting at in my comment above: I believe the only valid nucleotide pairs are `AA, AT, TT, TA, CC, CG, GG, GC`, i.e., only `A` and `T` can pair (with each other and themselves), and same goes for `G` and `C`.

Comment: Yes, biologically that's true that adenosine (`A`) only forms base pairs with thymidine (`T`) and guanosine (`G`) only base pairs with cytosine (`C`). However, I interpreted the question to mean that there is a DNA sequence in the file and it is of interest to count how often the sequence `AA`, `AT`, etc. appear. The number of dinucleotide sequences sometimes reveals biological function, e.g. `CpG` islands.

Comment: Sure, I was just trying to point out that `itertools.product("ACTG", repeat=2)` produces a bunch of extra pairs that won't ever show up (assuming the DAN sequence is valid). For a very long sequence, running e.g., `seq.count("AG")` is a waste.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following you ddejohn. Here are some of the first few nucleotides from the [GRIN2D gene](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/NG_052829.1?from=5001&to=55057&report=fasta): `GGGACAGGGGATGCAGG`. Cleary the sequence `AG` appears starting at the sixth nucleotide even though A does not form base pairs with G.

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood. I was under the impression that if `A` cannot form a base pair with `G` then that particular pair wouldn't show up in a sequence. Again, I'm not a biologist!